# Opening Second Form from First in Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm new to Qt and learning.

I have created two forms using Qt Designer. I want to open the second form from first on button click event. I have done this it is not working.

```
import LoginForm
import SignUpForm
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

def OnSignup():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = SignUpForm.Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = LoginForm.Ui_LoginForm()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

ui.Signup.clicked.connect(OnSignup)

MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**sys.exit(app.exec_())**

without this line first form open but second form not shown on clicking the button.

with this line, this error generated. **QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running**

Plz Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import LoginForm
import SignUpForm
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

window2 = None
def OnSignup():
    global window2
    if window2 is None:
        window2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = SignUpForm.Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(window2)
    window2.show()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = LoginForm.Ui_LoginForm()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

ui.Signup.clicked.connect(OnSignup)

MainWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: `def OnSignup():
    #app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = SignUpForm.Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_()) `

Comment: No need the app variable in the OnSignup function

Comment: `def OnSignup():
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = SignUpForm.Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()`   On clicking the button there is no resopnce

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: `def OnSignup():
    Window2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = SignUpForm.Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(Window2)
    Window2.show()`  Not Working, I think i am not getting your point

Comment: This Code working Fine  `window2 = None
def OnSignup():
    global window2
    if window2 == None:
        window2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = SignUpForm.Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(window2)
        window2.show()`

Comment: i think there is an error in line `global window2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()` it must be in two line `global window2 window2 = QtWidgets.QMainWind ow()` Thanks ....:)